# Regex allow dot and comma

Tags: regex

I have got this expression:

```
^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$
```

and it works fine except that I would like it to accept a comma as a separator as well. With this pattern, `1,5` or `,123` is false. It should be true.

Specifically,

```
0 = false
0.0 = false
null = false
. = false
, = false
0.123 = true
0,123 = true
.123 = true
,123 = true
123.123 = true
123,123 = true
```

Comment: Like [`^(?!0*[.,]?0+$)\d*[.,]?\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/fD7aO9/1)? I do not understand your *Neg or Pos* and *null* example.

Comment: I removed the Neg or Pos. I was trying to exlcude a prefix of - or +.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
^(?!0*[.,]?0+$)\d*[.,]?\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD7aO9/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0*[.,]?0+$)` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if the whole string is equal to 0+ zeros followed with 1 or 0 commas or dots and followed with one or more zeros (if the value is `0000`, `0`, `0,000`, or `.000`, or `,000`, etc.)
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `[.,]?` - an optional comma or dot
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Remember that you do not need `^` and `$` when using the pattern with the `String#matches` method, but it is a good idea to keep them explicit in the pattern for better readability and further testing.

Comment: Thank you!, the bracket is what threw me off. This is exactly what the expression should be to meet my requirement.