# Seperating numbers, punctuation and letters trought the whole case

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to achieve:
Split the string into separate parts of numbers, punctuation(except the . and , these should be found in the number part), and letters.
Example:

**Case 1:**
C_TANTALB

```
Result:

Alpha[]: C, TANTALB
Beta[]:
Zeta[]: _
```

**Case 2:**
BGA-100_T0.8

```
Result:

Alpha[]: BGA, T
Beta[]: 100, 0.8
Zeta[]: -, _
```

**Case 3:** C0201

```
Result:

Alpha[]: C
Beta[]: 0201
Zeta[]:
```

[I've found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968049/how-to-separate-character-and-number-part-from-string) but it doesn't the entire job for me as it fails on example 1 not returning even the alpha part. And it doesn't find the punctuation.

Any help would be appricated.

Comment: Answers there has `IsLetter` and `IsDigit`.. perhaps a simple combinaison of those will find the punctuation.

Comment: I'm going to keep that in mind, but this would be quite a heavy operation to iterate trough all the chars. This function is called on often and I would like to know if it's possible in a more efficient way

Comment: Are those strings based on some encoding standard? Is "-" and "_" the only "punctuation" possible?

Comment: The only way to test all the char of a string is to iterate on it. Those are simple operation I would not expect any performance issue. You can try using regex. like `([a-zA-Z]+)|(\d+)|([^a-zA-Z\d])`. you can even add name group

Comment: what happens if you have multiple - or _ ?

Comment: Are they still consecutive char of the same type? and be handle like "abc" <=> "-_-" or are punctuation unique and act as separator.

Comment: Maby this makes it more clear:
asdf78.32&*(#@hhkh#$#asdfh@#


Result:
Alpha: asdf, hhkh, asdfh
Beta: 78.32
Zeta: &*(#@, #$#, @#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If iterating the string an test with `IsDigit` and `IsLetter` a bit to complexe,
You can use Regex for this : `(?<Alfas>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<Digits>\d+)|(?<Others>[^a-zA-Z\d])`

#### 1/. Named Capture Group Alfas `(?<Alfas>[a-zA-Z]+)`

Match a single character present in the list below [a-zA-Z]+

> a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
> A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

#### 2/. Named Capture Group Digits `(?<Digits>[\d,.]+)`

\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

#### 3/. Named Capture Group Others `(?<Others>[^a-zA-Z\d]+)`

Match a single character **not** present in the list below [^a-zA-Z\d]

> a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
> A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
> \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Then to get one goup values:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(testInput, pattern).Cast<Match>();
            
var alfas = matches.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Groups["Alfas"].Value))
                    .Select(x=> x.Value)
                    .ToList();
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PRDGmJ)

Comment: Love your solution, one thing i want to catch the . and the , in the number group. I've changed the expression to :

@"(?<Alfas>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<Digits>\d.,+)|(?<Others>[^a-zA-Z\d])"

But that didn't seem to do what i was expecting , how do i need to alter the expression in order to catch the . and , in the Digits group?

Example:
XXX6.5YYY45

So 6.5 should be found as one match in the digits group

Comment: The original `\d+`, means multiple digits. Your version `\d.,+`, means One digit then a dot, followed by multiple comma. But rgex for numbers can quickly become complicated like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439618/regex-allow-dot-and-comma.

Comment: After trying some thing i've found this:```(?<Alfas>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<Digits>[\d,.]+)|(?<Others>[^a-zA-Z\d])``` still running some test but this seems to be what i'm looking for

Comment: It's need a set of rules more complexe than 6.5 => 6.5. What is the hundred and the decimal separator. because it can swap  depending of the culture. Are hundred separator exact(wellplace)? like "1,000" is 1000 and "10,00" is 10 and 00. Do we allow ".5" to be 0,5?*

Comment: `[\d,.]+` will allow ,.,.,.,.,..,.,. to be a number.. You can use some tool to play around and test if you have no set of rules https://regex101.com/r/n7iwGd/1

Comment: xdtTranform I've have to keep in mind both culture cases but I don't need to know it its a decimal separator. I just need them combined. That is no issue, that would be a very rare case and it won't match to anything I'm comparing it to. This will be used as a kind of auto-match for PCB component names.

Comment: With not particular rules, it will be enought. I have edit that into my answer. I didn't catch that part of the requirement

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted your awnser. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to do this is with 3 separate regular expressions; one for each class of characters.

- `[A-Za-z]+` for letter sequences
- `[\d.,]+` for numbers
- `[-_]+` for punctuation (incomplete for now; please feel free to extend the list)

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass
{
  private static readonly Regex _regexAlpha = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]+");
  private static readonly Regex _regexBeta = new Regex(@"[\d.,]+");
  private static readonly Regex _regexZeta = new Regex(@"[-_]+");

  public static void Main (string[] args)
  {
    Console.Write("Input: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    var resultAlpha = _regexAlpha.Matches(input).Select(m => m.Value);
    var resultBeta = _regexBeta.Matches(input).Select(m => m.Value);
    var resultZeta = _regexZeta.Matches(input).Select(m => m.Value);

    Console.WriteLine($"Alpha: {string.Join(", ", resultAlpha)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Beta: {string.Join(", ", resultBeta)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Zeta: {string.Join(", ", resultZeta)}");
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Input: ABC_3.14m--nop
Alpha: ABC, m, nop
Beta: 3.14
Zeta: _, --
```

Live demo: https://repl.it/repls/LopsidedUsefulBucket